# Inserting Twitter's json by field into MongoDB using python

Tags: python, json, mongodb, twitter

I have been working on this for hours and need some help.  This mostly works. I am able to connect to Twitter, pull the json data and store it in MongoDB however not all the data that I am seeing in my 'print(tweet)' line is showing up in MongoDB.  Specifically I didn't see the screen_name (or name or the matter) field. I really just need these fields: "id", "text", "created_at", "screen_name", "retweet_count", "favourites_count", "lang" and I get them all but the name.  I am not sure why it is not being inserted in the DB with all the other fields.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```html
from twython import Twython
from pymongo import MongoClient


ConsumerKey = "XXXXX"
ConsumerSecret = "XXXXX"
AccessToken = "XXXXX-XXXXX"
AccessTokenSecret = "XXXXX"

twitter = Twython(ConsumerKey,
 ConsumerSecret,
 AccessToken,
 AccessTokenSecret)

result = twitter.search(q="drexel", count='100')
result1 = result['statuses']

for tweet in result1:
        print(tweet) #prints tweets so I know I got data


client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
db = client.twitterdb
tweet_collection = db.twitter_search

#Fields I need ["id", "text", "created_at", "screen_name", "retweet_count", "favourites_count", "lang"]

for tweet in result1:
 try:
  tweet_collection.insert(tweet)
 except:
  pass

print("The number of tweets in English: ")
print(tweet_collection.count(lang="en"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following way:

```
def get_document(post):
    return {
        'id': post['id_str'], 
        'text': post['text'], 
        'created_at': post['created_at'], 
        'retweet_count' : post['retweet_count'], 
        'favourites_count': post['user']['favourites_count'], 
        'lang': post['lang'],
        'screen_name': post['user']['screen_name'] 
    }

for tweet in result1:
    try:
        tweet_collection.insert(
            get_document(tweet)
        )
    except:
        pass
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

The "screen_name" field is a subset of the "user" part of the tweet metadata. Make sure you're drilling down far enough.

Comment: That makes sense but down to I move into user and still import all the other data?

Comment: You may have to do pull out each piece  and combine the tweet and user data before you insert into mongodb. I'm answering from mobile so can't test right now.

Comment: Check out the examples under the "Twython Examples" section at this [link](http://stackabuse.com/accessing-the-twitter-api-with-python/).  It shows an example of how to pull the different pieces out and combine them in a dictionary which I assume you can insert into mongodb.